# Thermodynamic limit as zero-mass limit

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, many-body

Given a gas of $N$ particles, with mass $m_i$ of $i$th particle, in a volume $V$, usually the thermodynamic limit is achieved by sending $N, V \to + \infty$ while keeping fixed thier ratio $\frac{N}{V}$. However, I would like to know if it is possible to find a limit which allows to describe a high-density gas by using continuous expression rather than discrete, e.g. the density would be expressed by the integral $\frac{\int dm}{V}$ rather than $\frac{\sum_i m_i}{V}$. Can someone help me please finding a good reference where there is explained this limit?

I was thinking about modifying the usual thermodynamic limit by sending $N \to + \infty$, each $m_i \to 0$ while keeping constant the volume $V$ and total mass $M = \sum_{i = 1}^{N} m_i$, but I am not able to find any reference (book or paper) describing it, so I am not sure if that would work.